# Particle system objects rotated wrong

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, particles

[image]I was watching this video on how to make a battle scene in blender, but the video cut out before finishing. I got to the end but when I put my mesh down they're all on their side! I've used turned rotation on and off but it didn't do anything [image: my mesh[![][1]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gunDb.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Try changing the Initial Orientation in Rotation settings as indicated by the arrow. If the setting does not work try the other settings for Initial Orientation. One will work. You may need to go to the start of the particles frames and move through frames to see the result. The particle system display may need to calculate and play catch up.